# FPDF table content overlapping the cell

Tags: php, fpdf

I want to create a something which could work like dynamic table. Could because I knew how many cells it would be, but kind of because content I put into cell could be different length. I have used code posted of `fpdf` site:

```
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
class PDF extends FPDF{
function BasicTable($header, $data)
{
    // Header
    foreach($header as $col)
        $this->Cell(40,7,$col,1);
    $this->Ln();
    // Data
    foreach($data as $row)
    {
        foreach($row as $col)
            $this->Cell(40,6,$col,1);
        $this->Ln();
    }
}
}
```

and right now if i put into Table those values:

```
$header = array('Country', 'Capital', 'Area (sq km)', 'Pop. (thousands)');
$data =  array(array('a','a','a','a'), array('a','a','a','a'), array('a','a','a','a'), array('a','a','a','a'));
$pdf->SetY(45);
$pdf->BasicTable($header,$data);
```

everything is ok. But when I want to change my `'a'` into something more complex, like sentence made of few words, my text is 'leaving' the cell and it start to overlap the next cell.

Is there a way in fpdf to autofit cell?

Comment: I'm also having a problem on this one, Did you manage to solve this one? How?

Comment: I'm suggesting to check [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php) library. It seems it is more powerful than `fpdf`, so maybe this issue is fixed there.

Comment: @Eric, i did solve my problem but not direcyly> I used MultiCell to avoid overlapping, but I had to give up on vertical table alignment and instead of this create horizontal one. If you want i cant post here work around like I did

Comment: @Mithrand1r Can you post it here? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use FPDF::MultiCell() method, which is used to display multiline content.

In MultiCell, text will wrap and you won't have that problem.

You could also look at abstraction code over FPDF like [PDML](http://www.pdml-pdf.net/), or [HTML2FPDF](http://sourceforge.net/projects/html2fpdf/), or maybe TCPDF as stated before but i don't know this one.

Good luck with your project.